# What happens if a techeiles thread rips off?

Tags: tzitzis, techeles

I am aware that if you wear all white strings, if one of the eight reps, so therefore you still have 3 1/2 intact strings, it is still wearable. [(Source)](https://www.star-k.org/articles/articles/1219/mitzvos-on-the-fringe/)

Let’s say you are wearing two blue strings and two white strings. So now there is 4 of each hanging down. What if the blue string rips, leaving you with only 3. Would this still satisfy the mitzvah of Techeiles?

The reason I think it *may* be different is because of the requirements for the number of Blue strings. So perhaps if it were to rip it would change the equation.